# How do I use the aws-ebs-csi-driver addon when using the aws-eks-terraform module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Using an terraform-created eks cluster.  I am using the aws-eks-terraform module.  When specifying the aws-ebs-csi-driver as a cluster add-addon, I get

```
  cluster_addons = {
    coredns = {
      addon_version = "v1.8.7-eksbuild.3"
      resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
    }
    kube-proxy = {
      addon_version = "v1.24.7-eksbuild.2"
      resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
    }
    vpc-cni = {
      addon_version = "v1.12.0-eksbuild.1"
      resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
    }
    aws-ebs-csi-driver = {
      addon_version = "v1.13.0-eksbuild.2"
      resolve_conflicts="PRESERVE"
    }
  }
```

```
aws_eks_addon.this["aws-ebs-csi-driver"]: Modifying... [id=it-tooling-eks-8fmuw5:aws-ebs-csi-driver]
╷
│ Error: error updating EKS Add-On (it-tooling-eks-8fmuw5:aws-ebs-csi-driver): InvalidParameter: 1 validation error(s) found.
│ - minimum field size of 1, UpdateAddonInput.ServiceAccountRoleArn.
```

Answer (score 6):

[Friedrich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74648633/10871073) is correct. Here's mine but without terragrunt:

```
locals {
  ebs_csi_service_account_namespace = "kube-system"
  ebs_csi_service_account_name = "ebs-csi-controller-sa"
}

module "ebs_csi_controller_role" {
  source                        = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-assumable-role-with-oidc"
  version                       = "5.11.1"
  create_role                   = true
  role_name                     = "${var.cluster_name}-ebs-csi-controller"
  provider_url                  = replace(module.eks.cluster_oidc_issuer_url, "https://", "")
  role_policy_arns              = [aws_iam_policy.ebs_csi_controller.arn]
  oidc_fully_qualified_subjects = ["system:serviceaccount:${local.ebs_csi_service_account_namespace}:${local.ebs_csi_service_account_name}"]
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "ebs_csi_controller" {
  name_prefix = "ebs-csi-controller"
  description = "EKS ebs-csi-controller policy for cluster ${var.cluster_name}"
  policy      = file("${path.module}/policies/ebs_csi_controller_iam_policy.json")
}
```

And for the EKS module:

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "19.0.4"

  cluster_name    = var.cluster_name
  cluster_version = "1.24"

  vpc_id                   = var.vpc_id
  subnet_ids               = var.private_subnets
  control_plane_subnet_ids = var.intra_subnets

  cluster_endpoint_public_access  = false
  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true

  enable_irsa = true

  cluster_addons = {
    kube-proxy = {
      addon_version = "v1.24.7-eksbuild.2"
      resolve_conflicts="PRESERVE"
    }
    vpc-cni    = {
      addon_version = "v1.11.4-eksbuild.1"
      resolve_conflicts="PRESERVE"
    }
    coredns = {
      addon_version = "v1.8.7-eksbuild.3"
      configuration_values = jsonencode({
        computeType = "Fargate"
      })
      resolve_conflicts="PRESERVE"
    }
    aws-ebs-csi-driver = {
      service_account_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/${var.cluster_name}-ebs-csi-controller"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's two pieces you need to get the EBS CSI driver working:

- An IAM Role with the correct permissions as defined by AWS.
- An install of the CSI driver on the cluster.

For the driver install, there's a helm chart and an add-on. The add-on is much easier to set up.

The [terraform-aws-modules](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules) organization has terraform modules available that make it very easy to set up.

The [`iam-role-for-service-accounts-eks`](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-iam/tree/v5.14.0/modules/iam-role-for-service-accounts-eks) module will configure the IAM Role exactly as you need in a very clean way.

With the role set up, you just need to pass the ARN to the add-on.

```
module "ebs_csi_irsa_role" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-role-for-service-accounts-eks"

  role_name             = "${var.cluster_name}-ebs-csi"
  attach_ebs_csi_policy = true

  oidc_providers = {
    ex = {
      provider_arn               = module.eks.oidc_provider_arn
      namespace_service_accounts = ["kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa"]
    }
  }
}

module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "v19.10.0"

  cluster_name    = var.cluster_name

  ...

  cluster_addons = {
    aws-ebs-csi-driver = {
      service_account_role_arn = module.ebs_csi_irsa_role.iam_role_arn
      most_recent = true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's dependency cycle in this code

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is use this:

```
  cluster_addons = {
    aws-ebs-csi-driver = {
      service_account_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/amazon-eks-ebs-csi-driver-role-8fmuw5"
      addon_version = "v1.13.0-eksbuild.2"
      resolve_conflicts="PRESERVE"
    }
  }
```

You need the role, and associated policy for things to work properly.  I am including terragrunt scripts (terragrunt=terraform wrapper that uses terraform modules), in the hope that this helps someone.

ROLE

```
terraform {
  source = "${format("%s%s", dirname(get_parent_terragrunt_dir()), "/..//modules/terraform-aws-iam/modules/iam-assumable-role-with-oidc")}"
}

include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

dependencies {
  paths = [
    "../../../../once-per-account/policies/ebs-csi-driver-policy",
    "../../../../once-per-account/policies/ebs-csi-kms-encryption-policy",
    "../../random-string-env",
    "../../eks"
  ]
}

dependency "ebs-csi-driver-policy" {
  config_path = "../../../../once-per-account/policies/ebs-csi-driver-policy"
}

dependency "ebs-csi-kms-encryption-policy" {
  config_path = "../../../../once-per-account/policies/ebs-csi-kms-encryption-policy"
}

dependency "random-string" {
  config_path = "../../random-string-env"
}

dependency "eks" {
  config_path = "../../eks"
}

inputs = {
  create_role       = true
  role_requires_mfa = false
  role_name         = "amazon-eks-ebs-csi-driver-role-${dependency.random-string.outputs.random_suffix}"

  tags = {
    Role = "amazon-eks-ebs-csi-driver-role-${dependency.random-string.outputs.random_suffix}"
  }

  provider_url                   = dependency.eks.outputs.cluster_oidc_issuer_url
  role_policy_arns               = [dependency.ebs-csi-driver-policy.outputs.arn,dependency.ebs-csi-kms-encryption-policy.outputs.arn]
  oidc_fully_qualified_audiences = [ "sts.amazonaws.com" ]
  oidc_fully_qualified_subjects  = ["system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa"]
}
```

Policy

```
terraform {
  source = "${format("%s%s", dirname(get_parent_terragrunt_dir()), "/..//modules/terraform-aws-iam/modules/iam-policy")}"
}

include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

inputs = {
  name   = "AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicyNew"
  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:AttachVolume",
                "ec2:DetachVolume",
                "ec2:ModifyVolume",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumesModifications"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:snapshot/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": [
                        "CreateVolume",
                        "CreateSnapshot"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:snapshot/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/ebs.csi.aws.com/cluster": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/CSIVolumeName": "*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/kubernetes.io/cluster/*": "owned"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/ebs.csi.aws.com/cluster": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/CSIVolumeName": "*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/kubernetes.io/cluster/*": "owned"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteSnapshot"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/CSIVolumeSnapshotName": "*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteSnapshot"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/ebs.csi.aws.com/cluster": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: When using this policy be sure to replace the "\*" from the StringLike key conditions on creation and deletion with, in my case, the cluster name. As per the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html): "The **values** can include multi-character match wildcards (*) and single-character match wildcards (?) anywhere in the string." It has no mention of wildcards in keys.

Answer (score 0):

[Daverin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75377798/1974675) is almost complete except that it's still needed explicitly declare `aws_caller_identity` somewhere before using `service_account_role_arn` passing.

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
}
aws-ebs-csi-driver = {
  service_account_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/${var.cluster_name}-ebs-csi-controller"
}
```

here as answer given by Adrian's, my doubt is here the :role/${var.cluster_name}-ebs-csi-controller do we need to create this role fisrt